# Using EC2 command line tools with Access and Secret key only

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've been given access and secret keys for an EC2 account by a client, I know I can use Elastic Fox to start instances, but command line tools seem to require the account certificates. Are there any commandline tools which don't require the pem files?

Answer (score 1):

The new AWS CLI tools, which are available for many platforms, can use access key and secrets directly without the need for certificates and pem files.

http://aws.amazon.com/cli/

After installing, use `aws configure` to setup the keys you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the euca2ools can be used this way though some functionality is disabled, and most guides don't mention it: http://wiki.debian.org/euca2ools